# How to create drop down link like on dropbox

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropbox

For those who never visited dropbox, here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/

See the drop down menu link there for "sign in". how do i create drop down link like that?

[image]

Comment: Is it really a stupid question?

Comment: What specific part of it do you not know how to do? It looks like a regular form in an overlay. If you'd like to know how it is done, you can open the developer tools of your browser and inspect the code.

Comment: i am doing the same from an hour, i am not that good to decode complex css. I was learning. I only wish to make appear a small rectangular box on click of a button/link. As shown in image above. I searched about overlay, its not that. Kindly visit the given link to get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle. Just some Jquery.

```
<body>
<div id="login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <div>
        Login Form
        Lorem Ipsum blablbalbabababa lbablaabalbalba
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#login {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right:100px;
}
div#login:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
div#login div {
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    visibility: hidden;
}
body{height:1000px;}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","visible");
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jPPew/6/